# Interact.js - move iframe with a handle

Tags: javascript, iframe, drag-and-drop, interact.js

I have a iframe (blue border) with a handle (red div):

[image: screen]

I want to drag iframe (around the main document) using a red div handle. So, the red div stays in place, iframe moves.

I have created a fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/po70xko8/

which doesn't works the way i want (it moves red div inside the iframe instead). In the fiddle there's a code which i thought it will work, but it also doesn't:

```
    interact(iframe)
    .allowFrom(header)
    .draggable({
        onmove: onMove
    });
```

Is this even possible. How?

Many thanks!

Comment: does the handle has to be a part of the iframe content? If not you can put the frame in a parent div and also make the handle part of that parent.

Answer (score 3):

Working Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2mLutjzr/1/

If you want to move the `iframe` around the document you need to move the entire `iframe` not the `event.target`.

To move a iframe when to drag an element inside iframe, you need to call a method in the parent document to move the entire iframe. Due to some restriction in jsfiddle I couldn't use [parent](http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/iframes/refs/parent.php) method. So, I've made `onMove` as global by adding it to window. So, when `onMove` is called I'll `translate` the entire iframe from the parent.

```
window.onmove = function(event){
  //handled in the parent
}

interact(header)
.allowFrom(header)
.draggable({
     onmove: window.onMove //call the global callback
});
```

*The glitch in the drag is because of the interact.js*
*Hope you can fix that. You can achieve this drag effect using [drag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/drag) event without using any libraries*

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for you answert. Still I was not able to fix the glithching/jumping.

Comment: @rrejc That's the problem with the interact.js Try using the native drag events. That should work..

Comment: I'll try to do one example using that in my free time.

Comment: I am think of that (native drag events) too; I was thought that it would be easier to use interact.js instead of reinventing the wheel, but its not that simple as I thought it would be.

Answer (score 2):

Iframe didn't worked for me, so I've made slight change to your code you can find it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/vaygnmzy/)

```
var frameHtml = '<div id="wrapper"><div id="header" style="height:50px;background-color:red">Drag me</div><div id="content" style="background-color:green">Teh content</div></div>';
    var iframe = document.createElement("div");
    iframe.innerHTML = frameHtml;        
    iframe.id = "widgetWrapper";
    iframe.setAttribute("style", "z-index: 1000000;border:5px solid blue;");

    var p = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    p.appendChild(iframe);        

    interact(iframe)
    .allowFrom(header)
    .draggable({
        onmove: onMove
    });

    function onMove (event) {
        var target = event.target,
        x = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-x')) || 0) + event.dx,
        y = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-y')) || 0) + event.dy;

        if ('webkitTransform' in target.style || 'transform' in target.style) {
            target.style.webkitTransform =
                target.style.transform =
                'translate(' + x + 'px, ' + y + 'px)';
        }
        else {
            target.style.left = x + 'px';
            target.style.top  = y + 'px';
        }

        target.setAttribute('data-x', x);
        target.setAttribute('data-y', y);
    }
```

Comment: Hey, thats not a slight change, thats major change (div vs. iframe).Iframe is a must (for now).